# c#: define method in interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have read on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) that:

> Interfaces contain no implementation of methods.

But if I have the code:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Print(string message);
}

public static void FullPrint(this ITest test, string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
    test.Print(message);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITest test = new CTest();
    test.FullPrint("test");
}

public class CTest : ITest
{
    public void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

I have an implementation that is only for this interface.

So, in this case, does my interface contains a method or not?

Comment: You have no implementation of the method there. You only have the declaration.

Comment: Your code is missing `CTest`, which is the key.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `FullPrint` **receives an instance** of some type that implements `ITest`.

An interface, for this example the one named `ITest`, is essentially a contract definition. It is a promise that any types that implement that interface will contain the defined methods and properties of that interface. This is why interfaces do not have an implementation, it represents a promise/contract.

In your example again, you make a promise/contract that any type that implements `ITest` will contain method:

```
void Print(string message);
```

Your type (*not shown*) `CTest` implements that interface. You then create a reference of type `ITest` to the instance of `CTest`.

Comment: I've read on msdn that in expension methods,  their first parameter specifies which type the method operates on. so this has nothing to do with their concrete implementation, right?

Comment: @BudaGavril - its **extension** methods (*not expansion*). Yes and no, if you define the first parameter as an interface then that is true, if you define it as a class type and maybe that class type is sealed then yes.

Comment: @BudaGavril extension methods are not related to interfaces. Personally I think about them like a quick way to avoid using inheritance which in some cases can be pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have *declared* a method (giving its signature), but you didn't give it an *implementation*. Interfaces can't hold implementations, base classes can.

In your case it would mean you have to rewrite to:

```
public /*abstract */ class TestBase
{
    public virtual void Print(string message)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your case You implemented Extension method that can be used only on types declared as ITest. ITest Interface does not contain method FullPrint.
You can define you base class andimplement interface:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public void Print(string message)
    {
    // implementation
    }
}
```

Then, You can use that method in the following way:

```
ITest variable = new Test();
variable.FullPrint("Hello");
```